# Print TCHAR string to std::ostream when TCHAR can map to either char or wchar_t

Tags: windows, c++17, tchar, if-constexpr

I'm reusing the same exact same source file (for command-line parsing), in different executables. I don't use a library, and instead build that same source directly into each exe.

Recently I added an option to [list all shared-libraries used by the executable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/traversing-the-module-list). This worked fine in the exe I tested that on, but when I tried it on a different exe, it compiled but worked incorrectly, print addresses instead of the paths of shared libraries. I'm (*vaguely*) aware of TCHAR. Somehow, these two exes, which have different dependencies (brought in via CMake build), end up having different TCHAR types (`char` vs `wchat_t`). Both exes accepted `os << me32.szExePath` fine, but the first was calling `op<<(..., const char*)` while the second was calling `op<<(...,  const void*)`, thus printing addresses.

OK I thought, I'll just use a compile-time if (i.e. `if constexpr`) since I'm in C++17, and use `me32.szExePath` *as-is* in the `char` case, and explicitly convert it from `wchar_t` to `char` otherwise. The code below *fixed* the second exe, so it printed paths (instead of addresses). But then it broke the first exe!!!

```
1>...\CliContext.cpp(1703,81): error C2664: 'errno_t wcstombs_s(size_t *,char *,size_t,const wchar_t *,size_t)': cannot convert argument 4 from 'char [260]' to 'const wchar_t *'
1>...\CliContext.cpp(1703,55): message : Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt\stdlib.h(999,26): message : see declaration of 'wcstombs_s'
```

Which makes no sense to me, since the first exe shouldn't compile **both** `if constexpr` *branches*. After all, it can't have **two** values for the same `sizeof(*me32.szExePath)`, can it?

I'm obvious missing something... Anyone can help?

Is there a way to write this code so it works in both TCHAR cases, for printing to an `std::ostream`?

PS: I tried earlier an `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<wchar_t, *me32.szExePath>)` alternate compile-time if, and it similarly failed.

PPS: These are cross-platform exes. I'm not showing the linux side. I do want to use an `std::ostream` and not something else to *print*.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>

static void sharedLibraries(std::ostream& os) {
    auto dwPID = GetCurrentProcessId();
    HANDLE hModuleSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, dwPID);
    if (hModuleSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        raise("CreateToolhelp32Snapshot (of modules)");
    }
    using Handle_uptr = std::unique_ptr<void, decltype(&CloseHandle)>;
    Handle_uptr h(hModuleSnap, &CloseHandle);

    MODULEENTRY32 me32;
    me32.dwSize = sizeof(me32);
    if (!Module32First(hModuleSnap, &me32)) {
        raise("Module32First");
    }
    do {
        assert(me32.th32ProcessID == dwPID);
        if constexpr (sizeof(*me32.szExePath) == 1) {
            os << me32.szExePath << std::endl;
        }
        if constexpr (sizeof(*me32.szExePath) == 2) {
            size_t size = 0; char path[260*4];
            wcstombs_s(&size, path, sizeof(path), me32.szExePath, sizeof(path)-1);
            os << path << std::endl;
        }
    } while (Module32Next(hModuleSnap, &me32));
}
```

Comment: You should probably set `path` to `={}` so that it's filled with nulls.

Comment: `raise("...");` - is that a Windows specific overload? `std::raise` takes an `int` argument. `std::is_same_v<wchar_t, *me32.szExePath>` tries compares a _type_ with a _value_. That will never work.

Comment: Can't you just use `std::wostream`s when `std::is_same_v<TCHAR, wchar_t>`?

Comment: @MarkRansom Sure. Although doesn't matter here I believe, since `wcstombs_c` will write and null terminate it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Good point. I should have used a `decltype`. Thanks.

Comment: `raise()` is an internal helper, on top of `fmt::format()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using this worked for me:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
        size_t size = 0; char path[260*4];
        wcstombs_s(&size, path, sizeof(path), me32.szExePath, sizeof(path)-1);
        os << path << std::endl;
#else
        os << me32.szExePath << std::endl;
#endif
```

I'd still like to understand why the `if constexpr` failed though. FWIW.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if "Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. if constexpr is not a substitute for the #if preprocessing directive"

Comment: @Luke Ah! That's the part I was missing. Thanks. Must have used it in a template before, and wrongly assumed to carried over to *regular* code.